# How to "join" sub-matrices to create larger matrices on Python?

Tags: python, matrix

For $m < n$ suppose I have sampled a $m \times m$ random matrix and a $m \times (n-m)$ random matrix. I want to be able to join the later to the right of the former and create a $m \times n$ random matrix.

- Can someone kindly suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: Assuming you're using NumPy,  you will want to use the concatenate function. Without a concrete example, this is as much help as I can offer.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to to use the concatenate function to do this? 

I am not seeing what more concrete example I can give here.

Comment: You could give some code showing the production of the matrices. We're not sure if these are numpy arrays or 2d python lists

Answer (score 0):

Solution with numpy arrays:

```
import numpy
# assuming m2 and m1 are already created
m3 = numpy.concatenate((m2, m1), axis=1)
```

With m2 being m x m, and m1 being m x (n-m).

For 2d matrices, axis=0 concatenates them vertically, axis=1 concatenates them horizontally.

You could also look into `numpy.hstack()`.

Read the docs, they tell you exactly what these functions do and how to use them.